# What is the function of these electronic components in a Lego battery box?

Tags: batteries

I opened the Lego battery box, a picture is attached, [since the motor I'm connecting to it doesn't work as expected] and I discovered some electronic components there, which I suspect were burned.

Therefore, I want to understand what the function of each component is, and why they were put in a simple battery box, which I would not have expected to have any electronic component there, but a simple connection to the batteries and a simple three-position switch, and one check light.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. PTC "resettable fuse" 1.1A nominal
2. Series 2.7kΩ resistor for the LED
3. Schottky flyback diode to protect the LED and perhaps more

If the box is non-functional, the only component (not counting the switch) that would likely be at fault would be R2. Other possibilities are the PCB itself, soldering of R2 etc, bad connections to the battery holder contacts, batteries (obviously) and the switch.